# Error: Function 'vsrnggaussian' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type

Tags: gcc, random, fortran, gfortran, normal-distribution

I'm new to Fortran (gcc version 10.2.0) and try to use the subroutine 'vsrnggaussian' to generate normally distributed random numbers but always get following error:

"Error: Function 'vsrnggaussian' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type"

I don't get it since 'vsrnggaussian' is no variable that needs to be defined.

What's wrong with my code?

```
    program test_normaldistr_random_number
!
      USE iso_fortran_env, dp=>real64
!
      IMPLICIT NONE
!
      INTEGER :: VSL_RNG_METHOD_GAUSSIAN_BOXMULLER
      REAL(DP) :: n=1._dp, a=10._dp, sigma=2._dp, stream=1._dp
      REAL :: r = 1, status
!
      status = vsrnggaussian(VSL_RNG_METHOD_GAUSSIAN_BOXMULLER,
     &stream, n, r, a, sigma)
!
      print *, status
!
      end program
```

Comment: You.ned to provide the interface to the function in some way. I am sure we have a duplicate.

Comment: Alse, welcome at SO and be sure to take the Welcome [tour].

Comment: While the question in the first link has a slightly different error message, the accepted answer perfectly applies and explains the issue thoroughly. There are some other questions with the exact same error message as yours that apply to your problem less directly.